# Understanding EGSM-900 (LTE 8 band) electromagnetic spectrum

Tags: gsm, spectrum-analyzer

I am trying to fully understand the physical layer of the GSM standard. For doing that I am looking at the E-GSM-900 band (mostly used in Europe). In my country these frequencies has been assigned to the network operators as follow:

```
Table headers: Block, Uplink, Downlink, Operator, Concession, Expiration
```

[image]

So I set my spectrum analyzer to see the Downlink frequencies for that band (925.1 - 959.9 MHz):

- Central frequency: 940 MHz
- Frequency span: 30 MHz

And I am able to see this:
[image]
[image]
[image]

According to *ETSI TS 136 211 V10.0.0* the modulations used are:

- Downlink: OFDM
- Uplink: SC-FDMA

And looking into the next spectrum intervals:

- 930 - 935 MHz
- 940 - 945 MHz
- 950 - 955 MHz

It seems to me that it looks like OFDM modulated signals. But what is the first chunk preceding this OFDM blocks? Precisely the intervals:

- 925 - 930 MHz
- 940 - 945 MHz

What are they? Which signals are modulated there and in which modulation schema? I do not know if I am looking to the wrong standard (there is this huge mess between GSM-LTE bands), or if it is just my network analyzer configuration, or something else. I hope you shed some light on this.

EDIT: Added waterfall and time snapshot

Comment: Since no time duration is shown, also include the waterfall display. The spectra changes between idle negotiation and connection.

Comment: Examine the time slots over a 120ms interval.

Comment: Added! Very interesting note. I ve been observing the spectrum but I does not seem to change a lot. What I have seen is that yesterday the spectrum peaks where different (the no OFDM part)

Comment: you got everything  but a 120ms frame... ! like a 20s waterfall and a 10 us sweep,   looking for all the caller channels in a 120 ms frame then sub frame should appear. then adjust trigger